# Any way to "follow" PHP headers?

Tags: php

I'm having a problem where my script is redirecting to a location using `header()`. However, it's a headache to debug this since I have so many functions that send headers. Is there any debug feature in PHP that allows me to follow the headers? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a quick way would be to install APD and replace/hook the header function

take a look at the [`override_function`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php) it would permit to define your own `header` function with some logging.

a brute force solution would be also to replace all the `header(` by `header2(` for example so you can write your own function with some trace.

**Warning:** don't do this on your production machine because APD have a big performance impact.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a logging framework and you can use [headers_list()](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php) to get the headers.

Answer (score 0):

try running your webbrowser through paros proxy. You can see any kind of header sent between client and server